# ios rotate and slide image on circle view for Clock

Tags: ios, clock

i am making a clock application, in this app i have set a alarm , and client need alarm to set on analog clock , when user slide finger to button(image) on time button also rotate with finger and set time in label , Here i add image , if you have any link please share with me , 
[image]

Comment: Are you wanting the red blob to move with the user's finger to set the alarm time?

Comment: yes , i have search on code4app website but i have get only clock , problem is how to set alarm

Comment: @troop231 , please help me , if you have answer ....

Comment: Problem is, a touch on the red blob will only set the minute, not hour

Comment: please share with me code , at least any hope is there , i'll Try to solved this problem ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey [analoge clock](https://github.com/nacho4d/ClockView) i hope this code helpfull you.